# Finite Axiomatization of NBG and Foundation

Tags: set-theory

Does Mendelson's variant of Finite axiomatization of Class Comprehension Scheme of $NBG$ (referenced  below) require Foundation? In other words: Is axiom of Regularity necessary for deriving all axioms of class comprehension schema of $NBG$ from Mendelson's finite set of axioms?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory

Best regards,

Zuhair

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Are you asking whether Mendelson needs the foundation axiom to derive the other forms of comprehension from his axiom? Or are you asking whether his axiom implies foundation? Both answers are negative, I believe, but I'm unclear what you're asking.

Comment: The first, i.e.is axiom of Regularity necessary for deriving all class comprehension axioms from Mendelson's finite set of axioms?